# captured photo have grey line at bottom and size of image is very small in codenameone

Tags: java, codenameone

I am capturing an image, and I am storing it in my file system. Whereas I preview the photo by reading the byte stream.

Somewhere its not reading the byte data completely due to which I get the dark line at bottom of image. How I can use readfully() or readAll() here. When I tried using readall() method, the half of image didnt load properly. So, I am confused how to use this. I cant use File URI here as my image is having unique ID. Its working fine on simulator, but having issue on device. Any help on this would be really appreciated like how to use readfully() or readAll() method if that's the only solution.

```
public void saveFromFile(final String file, final boolean launchPreviewIfAnnotateAllowed) {

        FileSystemStorage fss = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
        InputStream is = fss.openInputStream(file);


            final byte[] bytes = getBytes(is);
            is.close();
            is = null;


            model.updateMediaData(bytes);


            Image im = Image.createImage(bytes, 0, bytes.length);


}

private static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {

    int len;
    int size = 1024;
    byte[] buf;

    if (is instanceof ByteArrayInputStream) {
        size = is.available();
        buf = new byte[size];
        len = is.read(buf, 0, size);
    } else {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        buf = new byte[size];
        while ((len = is.read(buf, 0, size)) != -1)
            bos.write(buf, 0, len);
        buf = bos.toByteArray();
    }
    return buf;
}
```

the updateMediaData() looks something like this

```
public void updateMediaData(byte[] binaryData) {
    updateMediaData(binaryData, null);
}

public void updateMediaData(final byte[] binaryData, final String filename) {

    mcHelper.updateMediaData(binaryData, photoId, filename);

}

  public void updateMediaData(byte[] binaryData, String componentId, String filename) {



    if (binaryData != null) {

        String userName = pj;
        userName = Strings.replaceAll(userName, " ", "_");  //USERNAME RENAME
        //now strip any bizzare chars from it
        String altered = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < userName.length(); i++) {
            char c = userName.charAt(i);
            if (c == '_' || Character.isDigit(c) || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')) {
                altered += c;
            }
        }

        userName = altered;

        final String muid = userName + DateTime.getMediaFileTimeStamp() + "_" + new Guid() + "_" + componentId 
                + "." + getExtension(binaryData);
        mediaData = new MediaData(muid);
        mediaData.setFormFieldId(owner.getIdInt());
        mediaData.setMediaType(MediaData.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO);
        if (muid != null && muid.indexOf(".jpg") != -1) {
            mediaData.setFilename(muid); 
        }
        else {
            mediaData.setFilename(filename != null ? filename : muid); // If filename isn't specified, use MUID. 
        }
        mediaData.setRevisionNumber(0);
        mediaData.setData(binaryData);
        mediaData.setMimeType(getMimeType(binaryData));
        if (mediaData.getMimeType().indexOf("octet-stream") != -1) {
            mediaData.setMimeType("image/jpeg"); //can happen when encrytion used
        }
        // Save the data to persistent storage.
        try {
            mm.saveData(mediaData);
        } catch (DataAccessException e) {
            Application.log(Application.LOG_LEVEL_WARNING, "Failed to save media data for MediaComponent.", e);
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: That looks like someone drew on the bottom of the picture since the line is uneven. Does it happen only on a specific device? Does it always happen in the same way? How do you invoke the capture code? Do you see if it you use a `Label` and not an `ImageViewer`? FYI if you use an `ImageViewer` you should place it in the center of a border layout and not in a flow layout as it allows zooming/panning.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Thanks for replying. No it happens on all device. Yes it always happens in same way. And the image to be placed on ImageViewer is created using byteData. That is, final Image im = Image.createImage(byteData, 0, byteData.length);
Thanks for pointing out about BorderLayout. I was about to change that.

Comment: In that case it looks like you didn't read the full image data when you constructed it. How did you load the image to the byte data and why didn't you just use the file URI?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I cant use File URI in my app because I have set unique id for each image. So I am setting with bytedata, it works perfectly fine on simulator have problem on device. The code I have used for writing bytes is as shown below. I tried using readall() that covers whole image. So, where I am going wrong. Thanks for help

Comment: I only see the read method, you need to edit the question and add the code there. Notice that your read method makes assumptions about streams. You should use `Util.readFully()` which doesn't do that.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog I edited my question. Please help me out of this. Thanks

Comment: You might also have an issue in `updateMediaData` but you didn't include the code for that

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Hi, thanks for your answer, it worked when I capture image from camera. But when I upload image from gallery I still get that and I use the same code as above to create image.And I added the updateMediaData() I used.

Comment: The update media method still invokes deeper to do the actual save. I suggest tracking this to see further misuse of the byte data. Here it seems you relied on the `available()` method which you shouldn't rely on.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `getBytes` with:

```
private static byte[] getBytes(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    Util.copy(is, bos);
    return bos.bos.toByteArray();
}
```

This performs the stream copy correctly.